# iOS/C/C++/Cocos2D: how to "simulate" an electric guitar pick slide sound

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, synthesizer

rather weird question I suppose, but lets put it in the right context. I am not looking for simulating the entire guitar sound range or for writing my own synthetizer, neaither to simulate an entire guitar ([please see answers to this type of questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814238/how-to-generate-a-real-bass-guitar-sound-either-in-c-c-or-java)). **I "Just" want to give an idea of the slide pick sound** without irritating a musician if possible. If the sound type is not clear please have a look here:

http://youtu.be/y4_wjNRLe4M?t=1m39s
http://youtu.be/VdrFTyUCGYs?t=2m57s

I'd like to give the user the sensation that if the slide bar is moved right a slide up sound is produced for a time lenght proportional to the relative movement of the slide bar. Instead if the user moves the slide bar left then a slide down sound would be played using the same concept.

For reference. I am using Cocos2D 2.0 and iOS 5.1.

I found something vaguely similar to the effect I am after the paragraph "Modifying audio properties" in Chapter 6 of [Cocos2d Cookbook](http://cocos2dcookbook.com/) (here is a link to a [free App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cocos2d-cookbook-ch4-6/id489395357?mt=8) from the demo examples of Chapter 4 to 6), where the author modifies a mono synthetizer tone changing the pitch and gain according to the user's finger position on the screen (see [this video](http://cocos2dcookbook.com/explore-the-book/chapter-6-audio/modifying-audio-properties/) to understand which example I am talking about in the case that is still unclear).

```
    //Play our sound with custom pitch and gain
    CDSoundSource *sound = [[sae soundSourceForFile:@"synth_tone_mono.caf"] retain];
    [sound play];
    sound.looping = YES;
    [notes setObject:sound forKey:key];
    sound.pitch = point.x/240.0f;
    sound.gain = point.y/320.0f;
```

This does not give the best solution but a decent approximation. Anyone would be able to suggest something better?

EDIT: I am working towards an approximation of this by recording a slide up and slide down sound equal to the maximum lenght. Then starting the sound once the slide pick bar is moved and stopping it once the movement is finished (in Cocos2d this will correspond to the touch started and touch ended on a particular sprite that will represent a slide pick). The slide pick will then be restored at the original position to avoid having to deal with the case where the sliding starts from different position. Of course is an approximation and I would use this because it is cheap in terms of development time and as well as computational performance (I guess that anything that will simulate the sound will be more "expensive" computationally). I leave the question open to see if anyone comes up with a better idea or solution (libraries are still wellcome because I am still considering the possibility to fully simulate the slide pick sound).

Comment: Just some info looking at your problem.  I don't believe that the sound is changing pitch.  It's actually a lowpass filter created by the distance from the frets methinks.  Another problem you face is the vibration of the surrounding strings which gives it that chord effect and the release period after you lift the pick.  What I would try is use granular synthesis to create a shifting window of grains you are playing while the user has his curser at a certain position.  Then jump grains to play the release period on loss of user interaction.  It's probably more complicated than you had hoped.

Comment: @Scrooch Thanks. I will look for some references and tuturials. I have left this aside for now but plan to do this in the new year. If you have any tutorials in the meanwhile please share :). Thanks!